# How to add disabled attribute to input tag with ngTagsInput?

Tags: html, angularjs, ng-tags-input

I have a custom directive that I use to manage user access through my website. I use this to add a 'disabled="disabled"' attribute to html tags.

However, when I try to use this with tag-input, it doesn't work. I'm guess this is down to that fact that ngTagsInput uses it's own directive for tags-input.

I have read the documentation and cannot find a solution to what I am looking for.

Here is my code:

Html:

```
<div access-level="Admin">
   <tags-input ng-model="tags" on-tag-added="addNewTag($tag)" on-tag-removed="removeTag($tag)">
       <auto-complete source="loadTags($query)" min-length="0"></auto-complete>
   </tags-input>
</div>
```

Is there any work around for this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's currently unsupported, but looks like will be in the next major version (2.3.0):
https://github.com/mbenford/ngTagsInput/issues/102

Edit:
2.3.0 is out; see following link for details https://github.com/mbenford/ngTagsInput/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#features

Answer (score 0):

I could not find this option in the release 2.3.0, but at least they have enabled the regular disabled attribute.
What I have done to hide the remove button and the "Add a tag" input box, was to add a couple of rules in the CSS.

```
tags-input[disabled] .remove-button {
    display: none;
}
tags-input[disabled] input.input {
    display: none;
}
```

Probably there is a better way to do it, this was the fastest I could find.