# ngTagsInput: disabling the input for tags upon a condition

Tags: angularjs, angular-directive, ng-tags-input

I am using [ngTagsInput](https://github.com/mbenford/ngTagsInput) to create some tags for my app.

My problem is: tag input fields refuse to `disable`. Namely, I would like to disable the input field when the number of tags is equal to one.

I checked docs but nothing there. Since `<tags-input>` is a custom directive it ignores the `disabled="disabled"`.

A [demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/RHm7H2?p=preview) of ngTagsInput.

The issue seems to be similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25767878/how-to-add-disabled-attribute-to-input-tag-with-ngtagsinput) one. It does not have any reply so far.

Could it be that the only way to solve this issue is by adding `disabled="disabled"` attribute into the `<input-tags>` directive in the source code?

Comment: Try `ng-disabled="true"`. Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34509624/ng-tags-input-how-to-disable-user-input

Answer (score 0):

Try this to disable the input tag:

```
ng-disabled="true"
```