# ng-tags-input, how to disable user input?

Tags: angularjs, ng-tags-input

I'm looking for how to the disable user input for this directive directive, what I want to do is the controller to insert values on certain events happening in the view.

I've went through the API and I didn't really find how to do this.
I've even tried using the `disabled` attribute

```
<tags-input ng-model="filterTags" disabled></tags-input>
```

What happened was the style turned gray, but I could still manually insert values.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

check this please,

```
<input ng-disabled="true">
```

Comment: what `ng-disabled` does is setting a `disabled` attribute according to the expression, in your answer the expression is `true`, so it's equivalent to just placing `disabled`.

Comment: yup, but i tried for <tags-input> its not displayed on html

Comment: did you include the directive in the app?

Comment: it works, my fault for missing this obvious solution. although it also works with `disabled="true"`

Answer (score 1):

In ***ng-tags-input.min.js***

---

1. Removing Close/remove Tag symbol : 
     a) Search for `ng-click="$removeTag()" ng-bind="::$$removeTagSymbol"`
     b) Delete these attributes
2. Making Tags Read only : 
     a) Search for  `<input class="input"` 
     b) Add `readonly` attribute
3. Removing "Add a tag" placeholder :
    a) Search for `Add a tag`, you will see something like `placeholder:[String,"Add a tag"]`
    b) Replace it with empty string , something like this `placeholder:[String,""]`

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uOrsg.png)